# Sort object by one of its values

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm trying to sort an object by one of its values from least to greatest. For example:

```
{
    obj1: {
        key1: something,
        key2: 54,
        key3: "something else"
    },
    obj2:{
        key1: something,
        key2: 27,
        key3: "another thing"
    },
    obj3:{
        key1: anotherSomething,
        key2: 78,
        key3: "whatever"
    }
}
```

Should, when sorted by `key2`, come out as `obj2`, `obj1`, `obj3`. Is there any way I can do this?

P.S. I've seen that there were some similar threads to this on Stack Overflow, but they were sorting it by an object that wasn't nested i.e. `{ obj1: 5, obj2: 3, obj3: 8}`

Comment: What you are asking is not possible - you cannot sort the properties of an object. As a workaround you could convert this to an array of objects, then use `sort()`

Comment: *"I've seen that there were some similar threads to this on Stack Overflow"* Whatever they suggest there you can apply here to.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is it okay if you use a sorting algorithm? I will give you a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the object to array (as you informed us in one of the comments), you could introduce an array with references to objects you wish to sort and then use the array to access those objects:

```
var obj = {
    obj1: {
        key1: something,
        key2: 54,
        key3: "something else"
    },
    obj2:{
        key1: something,
        key2: 27,
        key3: "another thing"
    },
    obj3:{
        key1: anotherSomething,
        key2: 78,
        key3: "whatever"
    }
};

var arr = [ obj.obj1, obj.obj2, obj.obj3 ];
arr.sort( function( a, b ){
   return a.key2 - b.key2;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to convert your object to an array. This is a must, because object fields are not ordered by nature. Here's an example of such an array:

```
var arr =
[
    {
        key1: something,
        key2: 54,
        key3: "something else"
    },
    {
        key1: something,
        key2: 27,
        key3: "another thing"
    },
    {
        key1: anotherSomething,
        key2: 78,
        key3: "whatever"
    }
];
```

When you have an array, you can sort its elements in different ways. For example, if you use Underscore.js, you can do this:

```
_.sortBy(arr, 'key2');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Firebase so I can't change it into an array :(

Comment: I dont knw  Firebase , but I am sure if it is supporting Javascript and js objects it will support arrays too. If you cant able to use underscore.js you can try some sorting algorithms. But you should not tell that arrays will not support.